# Width animation not starting from 0

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've created a div and set its width to 0 , when the page is loaded with document.ready i animate its width to 87%. Problem is that the width doesn't start from 0 but it starts out from 100% and then gets to 87%. Is there any way to make it go the other way around. I've tried using pixels ,changing it's position from relative to absolute , also swing animation but nothing seems to work.Thanks in advance

this is the code

HTML

```
<div class="rsch"><div class="teacherSlider"></div><div class="teacherContent"></div></div>
```

css

```
.rsch{
width:0;//850px
height:70px;
position:relative;
margin-top:9%;
margin-left:2%;
border:1px solid black;
overflow:hidden;
}
.teacherSlider{
width:17.5%;//17.5
height:100%;
position:absolute;
display:block;
background-color: #ff0700;
z-index:2;
}
.teacherContent{
width:82.5%;
height:100%;
left:17.5%;
position:relative;
background-color:blue;
z-index:1;
}
```

jquery

```
$(function() {
        $('.rsch').animate({
            width:"87%"
        }, 1000,'linear');
    });
```

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/uzn4ff32/).

Comment: it might be because it's surrounded by another parent container?

Comment: Please provide a minimally complete verified example.

Comment: it's weird man i tried using my whole code in jsfiddle and it also worked

Comment: ok solved it , it was because the css file was loaded after the javascript file

Answer (score 0):

It was because the css file was loaded after the javascript file.